# How do I copy messages from one kafka cluster to another?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I would like to copy data from a kafka topic on one cluster to a kafka topic on a separate host. I think this should be possible using a connector of some kind but Im not able to find the specific connector. Ideally I would be able to do some basic filtering in the connector based on custom headers. Also, I guess our enterprise architect does not want to allow us to use mirror maker.

- source: kafka cluster 1 topic
- destination: same topic name on kafka cluster 2 (filter any message without a specific header)

Comment: Have you tried kafka streams? Kafka Streams is a client library for building applications and microservices, where the input and output data are stored in Kafka clusters.

Comment: Thanks will check it out. I was able though to find a connector that does what I want (minus the filter). https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/3.18.x/reference/connectors/camel-kafka-not-secured-source-kafka-source-connector.html

Comment: Streams seems it's just a framework for creating a Java app which I could have course done anyway. The idea is to use a framework and not have to maintain the separate app. Your answer was mainly copied verbatim from here https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/index.html#:~:text=Kafka%20Streams%20is%20a%20client,Kafka's%20server%2Dside%20cluster%20technology.

Comment: AFAIK Kafka Streams is not able to push data to another cluster. Camel could be option https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/kafka-component.html#_samples

Comment: Yes as I mentioned earlier that is the solution I found. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clearly documented but [this](https://camel.apache.org/camel-kafka-connector/3.18.x/reference/connectors/camel-kafka-not-secured-source-kafka-source-connector.html) does seem to work after some experiments. It doest not have any filter option. They also have a secure version if the remote cluster is password protected.